# Google Maps API v.2 to v.3 conversion

Tags: google-maps, api

I want to go from
http://www.zolnai.ca/WMS/whereintheworldV2.htm
to
http://www.zolnai.ca/WMS/whereintheworldV3.htm 
I went through Gmaps API documentation on code.google.com and added the changes that I could find, but I cannot get the V3.htm to display anything.

Comments or suggestions please?

Comment: v3 is a complete re-write to include mobile applications, you have v2 references in your code - look at this v3 script and compare the differences - http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-v3/source/browse/trunk/xmlparsing/downloadurl.html?r=14

Comment: thx, and I tried to reflect that in my page suffixed v3, but I cannot get anything to show up but header, neither map not list

Answer (score 1):

In http://www.zolnai.ca/WMS/whereintheworldV3.htm you are missing the following:

1. Proper reference to the google maps api library. From v3 there is no need for an api key so the reference would look like this:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
   ```
2. There is no need for "new google.maps.Icon". You can simply use gicons["pink"]="0pink_Marker.PNG";
3. "new google.maps.Marker(point, gicons[icontype]);" is completely wrong syntax in v3. The right way of defining your marker would be: "new google.maps.Marker({position:point, icons:gicons[icontype]});"
   That is because in v3, the marker object requires a list of options in a javascript object literal, which in your case is: {position:point,icon:gicons[icontype]}

I am watching the code right now but it seems to me your code is a perfect mixture ofthe two versions. 
I recommend you checking the v3 api and picking it up!

Comment: thx for that! I looked for 2-to-3 change-list in vain, so I picked some up and missed some - indeed it is a "perfect mixture" until I ferret out all the v.3 diffs and get rid of the v.2 syntax - ul also look up the new G-api page.

Comment: Anyways, if you need help with any v3 stuff, just let me know, I'll be happy to help! :)

Comment: OK thx, do you know if a comparison table exists between v.2 & 3? As you can tell I ferreted out a few and you added more, but that doesn't cover all of them... ergo the v.2+3 mix you observe  :-)  Mapperz pointed me to a stock v.3 template so I almost considered rewriting the blessed thing, but so far I prefer to simply convert it - I think the structure is sound, only the syntax has changed, and I cannot find a dictionary!

Comment: Andrew, Have a look at this link, I think it will help you: http://mymonkeydo.com/converting-google-maps-v2-to-v3/ or https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference